# terror vs. the terror

Tags: articles

One book devoted to the well known and controversial period within the French Revolution is called "In defence of the Terror". Nevertheless the same historical event is officially described as *The Reign of Terror*. Is there some clarification for the different usage of the articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these names can be considered in any sense "official"; they're just alternative ways of referring to the same series of events.

So only one article is called for. The construction *The Reign of Terror* designates the time when (generic) terror reigned in public policy, not the time when *The Terror* reigned. *The Terror* is the same thing as the *The Reign of Terror*. To speak of *The Reign of **The** Terror* would be not only redundant but recursive: it would be equivalent to

> *The Reign of the Reign of The Terror*, which would be equivalent to
>   *The Reign of the Reign of the Reign of The Terror*, which would be equivalent to
>   *The Reign of the Reign of the Reign of the Reign of The Terror*, and so forth, *ad infinitum*.